# Single domain SSL certificates, actually support 2 subdomains?

Tags: tls, certificates

While browsing for SSL certificates, specifically domain validation type (the cheapest), I noticed that they advertise as valid for a single domain/subdomain, but then I noticed that they are valid for a single subdomain along with the root domain.

One of the certificates advertise as `Secures 'www' & 'non-www'`.

Is that common for domain level validation certificates ?, and should I expect all domain level validation certificates to be able to secure the root domain and a single subdomain ?

Answer (score 5):

I have seen it too -- my own server uses such a certificate, with two names in it: `example.com` and `www.example.com`.

The notion of "domain certificate" is not technical; it is a marketing term. From the technical point of view, an X.509 certificate contains a `Subject Alt Name` extension which may contain zero, one, two... or really many names of type `dNSName`. It is up to each CA to decide what it sells and at which price.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that at one time the `SubjectAltName` was not widely supported, but is now fairly common. However, DigiCert as well as some other certificate authorities still keep a client compatibility list available, e.g.: [DigiCert - Subject Alternative Names: Compatibility](http://www.digicert.com/subject-alternative-name-compatibility.htm)

If you're ever concerned about it, just spring for the extra cash and get what is known as a wildcard certificate. Your common name becomes `*.primarydomain.com`, and then redirect from `https://primarydomain.com` to `https://www.primarydomain.com`.